# How to calculate coordinates of equilateral triangle point from coordinate of centroids and rotation?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

For $ABC$ triangle with $H$ place in the centre of $[AB]$ and $[HC] = 5$

I want to calculate the $xy$ coordinate of $ABC$ from $G$ point centroids of $ABC$ triangle and for example a rotation of $60°$ of $[HC]$ in relation to the x-axis.

I have found the formula to determine the centroids from ABC point: $$Gx=\cfrac{Ax+Bx+Cx}{3 }\\ Gx=\cfrac{Ay+By+Cy}{3}$$ But I can't get it to reverse and add rotation parameters.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thanks I'm just looking for a way to do this ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a *circle* of centroid $G\left(x_G,\,y_G\right)$ and radius $R > 0$ can be parameterized as:

$$
\left(x,\,y\right) = \left(x_G,\,y_G\right) + R\left(\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta\right)
\quad \quad
\text{with} \; \theta \in [0,\,2\pi)
$$

the vertices of an $n$-sided *regular polygon* of centroid $G\left(x_G,\,y_G\right)$ and side $L > 0$ are:

$$
\left(x_k,\,y_k\right) = \left(x_G,\,y_G\right) + \frac{L}{2\sin(\pi/n)}\left(\cos\theta_k,\,\sin\theta_k\right)
\quad \quad
\text{with} \; \theta \in [0,\,2\pi)
$$

where $\theta_k = \theta + 2\,k\,\pi/n$, with $k = 0,\,1,\,\dots,\,n-1$.

You should now have all the credentials to adapt it to your needs, good luck! ^_^